# Upstart script exported by Foreman not working properly, respawning too fast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upstart, foreman

The only error I could find out was looking at `dmesg`

```
[  603.598951] init: thx4-web-1 main process ended, respawning
[  603.607935] init: thx4-web-1 main process (3901) terminated with status 127
[  603.607988] init: thx4-web-1 main process ended, respawning
[  603.616866] init: thx4-web-1 main process (3903) terminated with status 127
[  603.616917] init: thx4-web-1 respawning too fast, stopped
```

OS: Debian 7 , chruby (2.1.2), upstart (1.6.1-1) and foreman (0.74.0)

Only one process, to simplify the debug process in Procfile.staging :

```
web: RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec puma -e staging -C config/puma.rb
```

Generated files by foreman:

```
# /etc/init/thx4.conf
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

# /etc/init/thx4-web.conf
start on starting thx4
stop on stopping thx4

# /etc/init/thx4-web-1.conf
start on starting thx4-web
stop on stopping thx4-web
respawn
env PORT=5000
setuid deployer
chdir /home/deployer/apps/thx4/releases/20140707183433
exec RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec puma -e staging -C config/puma.rb
```

When i run `$ foreman start -f Procfile.staging` inside app folder, all it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved:

I created a .env file inside project root

```
# .env
PATH=/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.1.2/bin:/home/user/.rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin:/home/user/.rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:
RAILS_ENV=staging

# Procfile
web: bundle exec puma -e staging -C config/puma.rb
```

Exported file:

```
# /etc/init/app-web-1.conf
start on starting app-web
stop on stopping app-web
respawn

env PORT=5000
env PATH='/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.1.2/bin:/home/user/.rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin:/home/user/.rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin'
env RAILS_ENV='staging'

setuid user

chdir /home/user/apps/app/releases/20140709064220

exec bundle exec puma -e staging -C config/puma.rb
```

**Important**
I had to install gem bundler as root (i don't know), like i did with foreman here: https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/issues/276
`$ sudo chruby-exec ruby-2.1.2 -- gem install bundler`

Comment: The reason is because in your PATH you didn't append the original path in. If you change it to `PATH='/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.1.2/bin:/home/user/.rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin:/home/user/.rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin':$PATH` then you don't have to use bundler as root, but maybe because I am using rbenv so my situation is a bit different?

Answer (score 5):

Upstart logs your service execution in a log file by the same name in /var/log/upstart/your-service-name.log. It should be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control respawn interval, add something like this right after the "respawn" line":

```
# Please note that you need both "respawn" and "respawn limit".
# The second line will attempt to respawn no more than 3 times, 
# waiting 5 seconds between respawns.
respawn
respawn limit 3 5
```

However, I don't think this will help. Bash status code 127 means "command not found". Perhaps your gems aren't set up properly for this environment?

You can find more details about error #127 in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693127/2902848).

Comment: I did a lot of mistakes at configs, thanks for your answer the explanation about code 127 helped very much. The answer for my issue: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/468