# How to start the upstart process for golang application?

Tags: linux, go, amazon-ec2, upstart

I am using upstart to start my golang application. I have my application folder structure like this,

```
   web-app/
         /app
             main.go
```

I built the application as below,

```
$cd /home/ec2-user/go/src/github.com/dineshappavoo/web-app/app/
$go build ./...
```

It generated the binary `app`

And placed the `web-app.conf` in `/etc/init/` folder. Here is the web-app.conf content,

```
#Web app upstart script
description "start and stop web app"

start on (net-device-up
and local-filesystems
and runlevel [2345])

stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
respawn limit 5 30

console output

script
    chdir /home/ec2-user/go/src/github.com/dineshappavoo/web-app/app
    exec ./app
end script
```

When I tried sudo initctl list, it lists the process as `stop/waiting`. And I tried to start the process

$sudo initctl start web-app

It shows the process as `start/running`. But it is not started.

I checked the `/var/log/messages` logs. It shows,

```
init: web-app main process (18740) terminated with status 127
```

I couldn't start the process. I think there is some issue with the chdir. I tried different options for past two days. And I am fairly new to upstart but no luck. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Is the typo `rullevel` genuine?

Comment: What are you trying to execute exactly? app is a directory isn't it? take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692843/running-node-js-server-using-upstart-causes-terminated-with-status-127-on-ubu

Comment: ah that was a typo. Thanks for finding that. I fixed that and tried to start. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: @Lital - When I build the application it generates the binaries in the name app. [I think this is specific to golang]

Comment: Is the directory Web-app or web-app?

Comment: @Dany make sure the user who runs the upstart script has permissions to execute app.

Comment: @Lital - I run as root. I am starting the process from ec2 user data.

Comment: will it run with full path in the exec command (in addition to chdir)?

Comment: @Mark - Running outside of the directory with full path is not working. For example,
`$exec /home/ec2-user/go/src/github.com/dineshappavoo/web-app/app/app`

the above statement will throw error.
But the following will work
`$cd /home/ec2-user/go/src/github.com/dineshappavoo/web-app/app
$exec app`

Comment: Did you solve this? `status 127` means the binary wasn't found: either doesn't exist, was misspelt, or was invoked with `app` rather than `./app`. The `chdir` is ok otherwise you'd get a different error.

Comment: Note (on ubuntu) if `console output` is changed to `console log` in the upstart script, the stdout and stderr of the script and application will be logged to `/var/log/upstart/web-app.log`. This log may help explain why it's failing.

Comment: @Mark - I tried that option too.

Comment: @Mark - I tried 
`chdir /home/ec2-user/go/src/github.com/dineshappavoo/web-app/app
exec app`
But didn't help. I am not using ubuntu. I am using amazon linux in which I dont find `/var/log/upstart` logs.

Comment: Try removing the  `script` and `end script` (currently, ec2 uses an old version of upstart, and it might not handle the nesting).

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for helping me. I tried it with the following,
`export GOPATH="/home/ec2-user/go"
export GOROOT="/home/ec2-user/go"
export APP_STAGE="prod"
chdir /home/ec2-user/go/src/github.com/dineshappavoo/web-app/app
exec go run server.go`

also I tried `exec app`

In both cases application failed to start.

Comment: GOPATH and GOROOT are only needed for compiling. Did you try removing the `script` and `end script` lines? I spun up a new aws linux instance with your web-app.conf (identical except script/end script removed), and started a small go web server, and it's still up and running. With `script/end script` the logs were showing status 127 errors, as you saw.

Comment: @Mark - I really appreciate your help. I removed script and end script again and ran. When I used `exec app` it showed `initctl: Job failed to start`.  I changed to `exec ./app` it shows `process (18247) terminated with status 1` in the logs. :(

Comment: `terminated with status 1` suggests upstart is running your app, good! The app is crashing though. To verify the app is now the problem, temporarily swap `exec ./app` with a basic program you know to be working, eg, `exec sleep 2`. Restarting the job should result in /var/log/messages with several `web-app main process ended, respawning` lines.

Comment: @Mark - Great catch. Thank you so much.  I found the root cause with the technique you suggested. I use an environment variable APP_STAGE in web-app app server. Upstart is not taking this environment variable from console. So I updated the script 
`env APP_STAGE="prod"
chdir /home/ec2-user/go/src/github.com/dineshappavoo/web-app/app
exec ./app`
Finally it worked. I really appreciate your help. If you could add this as answer, I will accept.

Comment: great, glad to hear it's working :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP eventually solved after fixing a few issues. See comments, notably:

- upstart might not recognise environment variables
- Amazon Linux Image currently uses an old version of init (upstart 0.6.5), lacking newer features such as `console log` & nested script tags
- status 127 can occur if exec can't find the binary
- status 1 can occur if binary runs but fails
- substituting a simple program in an upstart script can help diagnose errors